# What is the exact process of resetting a password using Node.js?

Tags: hooks, services

I am using Node js as front end and drupal as backend, i am trying to develop a reset password api. As per my finding there are three steps for the same.

1. Request a Password (Send an email with secure time-bound link using
   **request_new_password** services resources)
2. Reset Password (Process one time login link and return
   **pass_reset_token** using **user_pass_reset** service resources)
3. Update Password by using **pass_reset_token**

I can do first and second steps easily, but how to update password by using **pass_reset_token**.

I saw [Using Services, request new password](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224551/using-services-request-new-password/235869#235869) but not very useful for me at least. how to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried npm package [`drupal-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/drupal-client)? The client is 7.x compatible and handles the auth overhead. It has a `resetPassword` method too.

Comment: @ShawnConn thanks, but i just want to explore the process of resetPassword

Comment: The `pass_reset_token` token is designed to be used in a redirect URL when a user initiates the password reset URL: `/user/{uid}/edit?pass-reset-token={pass_reset_token}`

As your linked Q states, the update endpoint makes use the same form. Have you attempted a PUT on `/user/{uid}?pass-reset-token={pass_reset_token}`? What did you see? Are you sure your node client is passing the credentials needed for authentication?